# Firebase deploy --only hosting error with next.js latest

Tags: next.js, devops, firebase-hosting, static-site-generation

I've created a next.js project with this command:
`npx create-next-app@latest testdemo`
And select these options to create:

[image]

After that, I've run it locally, it works fine,
build is fine too And the build create .next folder and within that, it created the server/app/index.html and many other files too.

then I want to deploy it to firebase hosting, For that I've login to firebase console and then

I've hit **firebase init** command
and select these options:

[image]

After that, the firebase.json is look like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I run this command:

```
    firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The commands works fine, But its the url is showing me this:

[image]

I want to know what i'm doing wrong here and why i'm not able to see the next.js application in that url.

I've tried to build and deploy the next.js application to firebase hosting but facing few errors.
I'm expecting to get the answer of my question from the experienced person.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use functions if you need servver side code. If you only have a front-end and not using API routes, you can export static site.

For functions check out - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting

For static export, update `next.config.js` to include `output: 'export'`

```
// next.config.js
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  // Optional: Add a trailing slash to all paths `/about` -> `/about/`
  // trailingSlash: true,
  // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
  // distDir: 'dist',
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

A Next.js application needs to run code on the server, which requires the use of Cloud Functions. And since those won't be deployed when you tell the Firebase CLI to deploy `--only hosting`, you end up seeing the default welcome page of Firebase Hosting.

So run `firebase deploy` without options, or `firebase deploy --only hosting,functions`.

Comment: Okay, and how to use the functions, can you edit your answer and give me an example?

Comment: It should work if you follow the documentation that is shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs) and [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools). If you can't get it to work, post a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck based on that documentation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have similar problem with deployment next.js application on Firebase Hosting. Application works no problem locally but after deployment on Firebase Hosting it showing "welcome screen" as an empty hosting. I do have Functions enabled and I'm doing full deployment using command: "firebase deploy". I've tried use emulator and I gat the same result "welcome screen". Logs are empty... where I can look for problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. Please put this change your `next.config.js` to the given code-

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Hopefully this will work.